# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML Only working correctly when it is used on a div tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've looked around and can't find any info on this.  My issue is this.  when i have react code like this:

```
<p ref="description" className="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.description}}></p>
```

and

```
this.props.description = "<p>this is a test</p>";
```

the html added via dangerouslySetInnerHTML is added under neither the description like this:

```
<p class="description" data-reactid=".0.0.2.2" style="height: 120.639999389649px;"></p>
<p>this is a test</p>
```

this seems to only happen when the string passed to dangerouslySetInnerHTML contains a block level element.  if the passed string is:

```
this.props.description = "<span>this is a test</span>";
```

it works correctly and outputs this:

```
<p class="description" data-reactid=".0.0.2.2" style="height: 120.639999389649px;">
    <span>this is a test</span>
</p>
```

if i change the code from so i use a div tag instead of a p tag like this:

```
<div ref="description" className="description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.description}}></div>
```

then dangerouslySetInnerHTML works correctly with block level elements and outputs this:

```
<div class="description" data-reactid=".0.0.2.2" style="height: 120.639999389649px;">
    <p>this is a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you're embedding html in an attribute, which is not permitted. it's obviously taking the route of assuming you wanted to insert REAL html. if you want html-in-attribute, you'll have to encode it. `foo="&lt;p&gt; hi mom &lt;/p&gt;"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React isn't doing this, your browser is. Putting a `<p>` element inside another `<p>` element isn't valid HTML<sup>†</sup>, so your browser does the only thing that makes sense, which is to put the second `<p>` after the first.

You can see the exact same behavior in this snippet, which doesn't use any JavaScript:

```css
p { width: 10em; height: 1em; }
#outer { border: 1px solid blue; }
#inner { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<p id="outer">
    <p id="inner">Hello</p>
</p>
```

<sup>†</sup>In the HTML5 spec the `<p>` element's content model is named "Phrasing content":

> **Phrasing content** is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level.

[Take a look at the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) for a list of elements that are valid inside a `<p>` element.

Comment: In my case, what happened is that the browser was doing this, as you say, and then React was removing the displaced paragraph during hydration, so instead of having my paragraphs un-nested, I just lost all my content. This result is definitely not "the only thing that makes sense", as the browser+react team are just loosing all my content. This is actually a source of difference between a server-side React render and a client-side (with the browser doing its unfortunate thing) render. I don't know what the best way forward is or anything, but this feels ripe for improvement, likely in React.